# how can i right-align Mui textfield text in version 5?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to right align the placeholder text in Mui v5 . sx wont work and I don't know how to do it using 'styled'
[image]

after i tried inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'right' }}} it was set to the element but not chaanged in ui(the placeholder text most be at the right side of the textField box)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `inputProps`:

```
<TextField
    placeholder="your placeholder"
    inputProps={{
      sx: {
        textAlign: "right",
        "&::placeholder": {
          textAlign: "right",
        },
      },
    }}
  />
```

Comment: text align is set to right  when I inspect the element but its not shown in ui

Comment: How is it shown in the ui, can you add some screenshots or further explain this.

Comment: i added it to the question

Comment: I can not understand what is not working:  https://ibb.co/WgrfkVR

Comment: i need the placeholder text to be at the right side of the textfield box

Comment: I've updated the answear. If you dont need the text align after input just remove the `style` object.

Comment: it worked thanks! do you know how does it work with label instead of placeholder? cause i need its animation and stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248568/discussion-between-fateme-hemmati-and-dobromir-kirov).